# Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches WritableServerSelector. state = connected

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java-driver, spring-mongodb

I am trying simple CRUD on my mongo server and I am getting this one

> com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while
>   waiting for a server that matches WritableServerSelector.  Client view
>   of cluster state is {type=REPLICA_SET,
>   servers=[{address=mongodb.mydomain.com:27017,
>   type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, roundTripTime=133.1 ms, state=CONNECTED}]

Spring mongo:

```
 <dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
 dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
      <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.4</version>
```

Mongo server:

> 3.2.21

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to write to the replica set so the solution was to add master node to mongo connection string.